# When recording a live stream with youtube-dl where am I supposed to set the duration of the recording?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

```
import youtube_dl
def record_stream(name, url, duration):
    opts={'outtmpl': name}
    youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts).download([url])
```

Given the code above, which parameter option sets the duration for which youtube-dl should record the live stream?

Using ffmpeg it was quite simple (`ffmpeg -i {url} -t {duration} -c copy  {name}`) but I am having surprisingly hard time trying to find such option in youtube-dl.

I would rather avoid hacky solutions like `timeout {duration_in_seconds}s python record_stream.py` and set the duration in youtube_dl.

Comment: Pass `postprocessor_args='-t {duration}'` in the constructor kwargs for `YoutubeDL`

Comment: Like this `youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts, postprocessor_args='-t {duration}')` ? If so it throws an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'postprocessor_args'`

Comment: Adding it to `opts` like this `opts={"postprocessor_args : "-t 00:00:01"}` does seemingly nothing, and the stream is recorded for much longer than 1 second (it seemingly goes on indefinitely)